# How can I apply animations to a list of elements one by one with angular 4 animation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I'm trying to apply angular 4 animation to list of html elements like

```
facilities = ['<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"> </span> Text 1</p>',
        '<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>Text 2</p>',
        '<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> Text 3</p>',
        '<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> Text 4</p>',
];
```

one by one with below code:

```
animations: [
  trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
      animate(100)
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(100, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

When I put this trigger to list elements, all the elements come on the screen all in one go. I want to make them appear one by one, like fetch text 1 and then text 2 on html. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
Using staggers:

**HTML**:

```
<ul [@listAnimation]="items.length">
       <li *ngFor="let item of items" >
          <div [innerHTML]="item"></div>
       </li>
</ul>
```

**Typescript:**

```
....
animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
   transition('* => *', [

     query(':leave', [
      stagger(500, [
        animate(1000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ], { optional: true }),
     query(':enter', [
           style({ opacity: 0 }),
 stagger(500, [
        animate(1000, style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ], { optional: true })
  ])
...
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqwn7b?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

It can be done with [Angular animation callbacks](https://angular.io/guide/animations#animation-callbacks) and with some help written in typescript

**HTML:**

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of listCopy;" (@flyInOut.done)="getNextItem()" [@flyInOut]="'in'" >
     <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of list" (@flyInOut.done)="getNextItem()" [@flyInOut]="'in'" >
           <div [innerHTML]="item"></div>
        </li>
     </ul>        
   </li>
 </ul>
```

**Typescript:**

```
   .....
   @Component({
   ....
   animations: [
      trigger('flyInOut', [
        state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
        transition('void => *', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
          animate(100)
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
          animate(100, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
        ])
      ])
    ]
    ....
    list = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'];
    listCopy = []; 
    next: number = 0;

    constructor(){
        this.getNextItem();
    }

    getNextItem() {
        if(this.next < this.list.length) {
          this.listCopy.push(this.list[this.next++]);
        }
    }
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q9EGP5hpOZtZV3jueB0o?p=preview)** (I put 1000ms to emphasise the animation)

Comment: How can I fetch a <p> element instead of just plain text?

Comment: What do you mean by plain text? {{item}} ?

Comment: yes.
I want to fetch something like
 <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"> </span> text </p>

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, why don't replace {{item}} by what you wrote above, what is the specificity?

Comment: Do you have a data structure?

Comment: Ok, but this is out of the scope of this question :) post a new one and will try to answer :)

Comment: I got what you are looking for, but again, as it is out of the scope of this question and to keep as it is for others, it's better you ask a new one.

Comment: I've edited my question @Vega, if you could update your answer please :-)

Comment: Done, I think your question post is not reflecting the real question. Put the comment content also

Comment: Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Now I see the exact text I want but it is fetching all elements in one go only. i.e. back to original question :-(

Comment: I am not getting you ... Your question was about animation and the code shows list items one by one and applying the animation. Have you checked the plunker?

Comment: Thank you mate. Below code worked. I think you added another un-ordered list in <li> by mistake which lead confusion. :-)
 `<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of listCopy; let i = index" (@flyInOut.done)="getNextItem()" [@flyInOut]="'in'" >
        <div [innerHTML]="item"></div>
     </li>
</ul>` 

If you could edit answer a little bit please.

Comment: That's great it worked, but I still don't understand what was the issue :( And could you update the question with   list = ['<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"> </span> Text 1</p>', '<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> Text 2</p>', '<p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> Text 3</p>', ], that changes the question a lot!

Comment: Thanks Vega, However, I've implemented the css animation later as angular animation wasn't helping.
It would be useful whoever is looking for this. thanks again